# CSS for selecting first span in all td's

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble visualizing my CSS and I am trying to reach all `td`'s first `span` with CSS, but all I am selecting is the very first `td`. What am I doing wrong?

CSS

```
.teamStats > tbody > tr > th:first-child {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="teamStats">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span id="stats0Name"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats0Double"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats0Triple"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats0Quadra"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats0Penta"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span id="stats1Name"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats1Double"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats1Triple"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats1Quadra"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats1Penta"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span id="stats2Name"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats2Double"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats2Triple"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats2Quadra"></span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats2Penta"></span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

TLDR: I am trying to set a style for all **stats#Name**, and I am struggling with mapping it to a CSS.

Comment: You want the first span, right, not the first th? So put the first-child on the span.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
.teamStats > tbody > tr > th span:first-child {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```css
.teamStats > tbody > tr > th > span:first-child {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="teamStats">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span id="stats0Name">this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats0Double">not this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats0Triple">not this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats0Quadra">not this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats0Penta">not this</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span id="stats1Name">this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats1Double">not this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats1Triple">not this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats1Quadra">not this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats1Penta">not this</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span id="stats2Name">this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats2Double">not this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats2Triple">not this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats2Quadra">not this</span>
            <br />
            <span id="stats2Penta">not this</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding demos @Danko and Alex Char!

Comment: I'd recommend `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child` in this specific case. It's a bit more resilient.

Comment: wow really?! >.> I could of sworn I tried that syntax too haha. Thank you! (accepting when timer expires)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes What is the difference between those two syntax? I figure the `first-child` would point to the "type" that is referenced before it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

```
.teamStats th span:first-child{
     ...
}
```

Comment: What element is he targeting that is not in the HTML, and what do you mean by "indicating direct relation"?

Comment: You still don't have it right. You want the first span, not the first th or td.

Comment: Yeah... misread the q and i just meant his selectors were requiring tbody to be in the html.

Comment: `tbody` **IS** in the HTML, even if not explicitly written in the markup. The browser engine will put it there.

Comment: ah ok, i wasn't sure if ALL browsers did that :)

Comment: They do. Having said that, there is really no need to do `.teamStats > tbody > tr` when you could just as easily do `.teamStates tr`, unless you want to make sure the rule does not apply to `thead`, or are worried about nested tables.